# Hot to remove ←[39m from mingw64 when executing artisan command

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, mingw-w64

I am having problem with mingw64 console.
When I execute artisan commands from mingw64 console each output line is prefixed and sufixed with "←[39m":

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). It's not a problem with Laravel or Artisan.

With a shell that properly supports them, it'll look like this:

[image]

I'm not aware of any way to turn them off in Artisan, so your likely options are a) put up with it or b) use a better shell. Cygwin might be an option.